# UIActionSheet displays not from the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactionsheet

I'm very new to iOS developing, so I got this problem and out of ideas of how to solve this.

Here's the idea: I have a single TableViewController in my app, and table consists of a few cells, where each includes an image, label and a button, and when you hit the button, the UIActionSheet creates and being displayed in the view.

So it seem to work and display just fine with portrait orientation, and for a first few cells in landscape orientation. But when I scroll a little down my table in landscape orientation, and hit the button, actionSheet never displays from the bottom of screen, how it was supposed to. Instead it shows somewhere above, in the middle of the screen or even on top. This happens only when I scroll my table down...

To show my actionSheet I use the following

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Here is what I keep on getting in iOS simulator:

[image]

Also, I am not using Interface Builder.
I am also not using any Toolbars or TabBars, to view actionSheets from there.

Help!

Comment: Frame of `self.view` when `UIActionSheet` is going to be displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Try it, I hope it will help!

```
UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
if ([window.subviews containsObject:self.view]) 
{
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
} else 
{
    [actionSheet showInView:window];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help... I've noticed, that in landscape mode actionSheet is always being displayed in the same area relatively to the table. So no matter how far I scroll down, it seems like actionSheet is fixed to some position to be shown, which would be the bottom of screen when the table hasn't been scrolled down yet... and yet still it displays as supposed in portrait mode.

Comment: @user3065769 Do you use tabbar?

Comment: I use neither TabBars, nor ToolBars to view my actionSheet from there.